# class keyword is not working in Khan Academy editor

Tags: javascript, html, class, khan-academy

This code throws the error "Unexpected reserved word" in the Khan Academy html editor. I am quite sure that this is a problem with Khan Academy's editor and not my code, but how do I fix it?

```
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        class Example {
            constructor () {
                
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are sure that the problem is with Khan Academy's editor, then the solution is, obviously, to use another IDE of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khan Academy's webpage environment uses a custom version of [Slowparse](https://github.com/Khan/live-editor/blob/master/external/slowparse/slowparse.js) to lint the HTML code before running it. This Slowparse in turn uses a version of [Esprima](https://github.com/Khan/live-editor/blob/master/build/external/structuredjs/external/esprima.js) nearly a decade out-of-date to parse any JavaScript code. As a result, the environment cannot parse classes which were only introduced in [ECMAScript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-class-definitions).

You can work around this limitation by exploiting the [incomplete set of valid script type attributes](https://github.com/Khan/live-editor/blob/fb69175850f3e27b4bc9303b37c4f889a7b50c74/external/slowparse/slowparse.js#L1948) recognized by Khan. Using any [valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type#value) other than no value (`<script>`) and `text/javascript` will circumvent the linting (and transformation) of the JavaScript code.

For example, using [`module`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type#module) with your code:

```html
<script type="module">
    class Example {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

The caveat here is that working with globals is not straightforward. Using the `application/javascript` media type with your code, for example, will silently fail (errors only logged to the browser console) because of a syntax error after the first run. This is because Khan doesn't properly [clean](https://github.com/Khan/live-editor/blob/fb69175850f3e27b4bc9303b37c4f889a7b50c74/js/output/webpage/webpage-output.js#L330) the environment between runs. You have three options to deal with this:

- use JavaScript modules keeping in mind the [differences to standard scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) (one of them conveniently being variables not global scoped by default)
- use a JavaScript media type unrecognized by Khan and write your code in a block scope (e.g. an IIFE)
- exclusively use the `var` keyword or no keyword to "declare" variables